# google colab pro issue, cannot access generative code ai assistant

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am have an issue with google colab pro. I subscribed to this plan to use the generative code assistant however I cannot access this feature. I am located in Germany at the moment if this info could be helpful.
Thank you in advance.

I tried to find colab customer service but there was none as they mentioned that I should post my issue either in github or stackoverflow.